# F# - Sorting a list of string tuple

Tags: list, sorting, f#, tuples

Ex.

> sortPairs [("Derek", "Christopher")]
> val it : (string * string) list = [("Christopher", "Derek")]

> sortPairs [("Parker", "Derek"); ("dora", "derek")]
> val it : (string * string) list = [("derek"; "dora"); ("Derek", "Parker")]

Comment: You can map to a function that sorts the tuples, then sort the whole list.

Comment: not completely sure what the questions is. Its takes each tuple and sorts it, then sorts the list based on the order of the tuple by ordering by the 1st element then the 2nd? Is it homework? If it is, I'd rather give help than an answer. Also not sure where the high order function comes in.

Answer (score 2):

First of all; some effort when asking a question would be nice.

But if I decoded the question correctly as being "How can I transform a list of pairs to a sorted list of sorted pairs" then I think the following would be a solution:

```
let sortPair (a, b) = (min a b, max a b)
let sortPairs pairs = pairs |> List.map sortPair |> List.sort
```